# How to convert parameter to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, parameters, case-sensitive

I'm very new to javascript and would like to learn to ensure a parameter is in lowercase.

In the example below, "ES" and "DE" parameters are not working because they are in upper case. How can I ensure these parameters are being converted to lowercase?

```
function helloWorld(lang){
    if (lang === "es") {
        return "Hello in Spanish";
    } else if (lang === "de"){
        return "Hello in German";
    } else {
        return "Hello in English";
    }
}

console.log(helloWorld("a"));
console.log(helloWorld("ES"));
console.log(helloWorld("DE"));
```

Comment: There is a .toLowerCase() built in function that you can call to make sure it's all lowercase.

Comment: toLowerCase() doesn't check that it's lowercase. It **converts** to lower case. **Note** The toLowerCase() method does not change the original string. If you want to change it then use @sgroves solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
lang = lang.toLowerCase();
```

at the top of your `helloWorld` function. Then `lang` will always be lowercase when you use it later in the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
lang = lang. toLowerCase();
```

Best way would be to covert your parameter to lowercase first and then perform any operations with it. This way you can make sure it is consistent and no matter what the case of you parameter is, it would always be lowercase.

```
function helloWorld(lang){
lang = lang. toLowerCase();
    if (lang === "es") {
        return "Hello in Spanish";
    } else if (lang === "de"){
        return "Hello in German";
    } else {
        return "Hello in English";
    }
}

console.log(helloWorld("a"));
console.log(helloWorld("ES"));
console.log(helloWorld("DE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function helloWorld(lang){
  lang = lang.toLowerCase();
  if (lang === "es") {
    return "Hello in Spanish";
  } else if (lang === "de"){
      return "Hello in German";
  } else {
    return "Hello in English";
  }
}
```

This converts the string to lowercase and stores in the original variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ToLowerCase() method
string.ToLowerCase()

in your case

```
console.log("ES".toLowerCase());
```

Comment: there is no `String.toLower` function in javascript

Comment: @user3798327 That method name is incomplete. Change it to toLowerCase()